# Trying to making a ledge. The problem: transform.position always returns to vector( 0, 0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, raycasting

I'm trying to make a method that lets players climb a ledge. I have two raycast one for Ledge and one for Wall detection. I the ledge is false, then climb the ledge.
Here comes the problem:
When the Wall check is true and the ledge Check is true, Set player transform.position to be near the ledge. Then afterward transform.position to be above the ledge. But for some reason whenever I try to call Set player transform.position near the ledge, it just teleports back to the default vector value 0, 0.

```
    [Header("Ledge check")]
    private bool canClimbLedge = false;
    private bool ledgeDetected;

    private Vector2 workspace;

    //NEW SHIT
    private Vector2 detectedPos;
    private Vector2 cornerPos;
    private Vector2 startPos;
    private Vector2 stopPos;
    [Header("Ledge Climb State")]
    public Vector2 startOffset;
    public Vector2 stopOffset;

private void FixedUpdate()
{        if (coll.isTouchingWall && !coll.isTouchingRightLedge || !coll.isTouchingLeftLedge)
        {
            SetDetectedPosition(transform.position);
        }
}

void Update()
    {
        DetermineCornerPosition();

        if (coll.onWall && !coll.isTouchingRightLedge)
        CheckLedgeClimb();
        if(canClimbLedge && coll.onGround)
        FinishLedgeClimb();

        if (dir.x < 0)
        {
            if (groundTouch == true && !wallGrab)
               // dustParticle.Play();

            if (wallGrab != true)
            {
                side = -1;
                //anim.Flip(side);

            }

        }

        if (dir.x > 0)
        {
            if (groundTouch == true && !wallGrab)
                // dustParticle.Play();

                if (wallGrab != true)
                {
                    side = 1;
                    // anim.Flip(side);
                }
        }
    }

public void SetDetectedPosition(Vector2 pos) => detectedPos = pos;
    public Vector2 DetermineCornerPosition()
    {
        RaycastHit2D xHit = Physics2D.Raycast(coll.wallCheck.position, Vector2.right * side, coll.wallCheckDistance, coll.groundLayer);
        float xDist = xHit.distance;
        workspace.Set((xDist * side) * side, 0.015f);
        RaycastHit2D yHit = Physics2D.Raycast(coll.ledgeCheck.position + (Vector3)(workspace), Vector2.down, coll.ledgeCheck.position.y - coll.wallCheck.position.y + 0.015f, coll.groundLayer);
        float yDist = yHit.distance;

        //Upper Corner Position of ledge
        workspace.Set(coll.wallCheck.position.x + (xDist * side), coll.ledgeCheck.position.y - yDist);
        return workspace;
    }
    private void CheckLedgeClimb()
    {

        if (coll.isTouchingWall && !coll.isTouchingRightLedge && !ledgeDetected)
        {
            ledgeDetected = true;
            //Freeze player in the detectedPos
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.gravityScale = 0f;
            transform.position = detectedPos;
            cornerPos = DetermineCornerPosition();
        }

        if(ledgeDetected && !canClimbLedge)
        {
            canClimbLedge = true;
            startPos.Set(cornerPos.x - (side * startOffset.x), cornerPos.y - startOffset.y);
            stopPos.Set(cornerPos.x + (side * stopOffset.x), cornerPos.y + stopOffset.y);
        }

        Debug.Log(startPos);
        canMove = false;
        transform.position = startPos;
        canClimbLedge = true;
    }

    public void FinishLedgeClimb()
    {
     //Call the last part of climbing the ledge
    }
```

In the Collision Script:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    isTouchingWall = Physics2D.Raycast(wallCheck.position, transform.right, wallCheckDistance, groundLayer);

    isTouchingRightLedge = isTouchingWall = Physics2D.Raycast(ledgeCheck.position, transform.right, wallCheckDistance, groundLayer);
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated, and if you have any other solution to make a ledge climber, I'm all ears.

Comment: Well in `CheckLedgeClimb()` you always set `transform.position = startPos;` could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reevaluated the purpose was with the script.
The problem was Raycast was not really working correctly
And instead of making the raycast shoot in one direction, I made it follow change 180 degrees if the player was facing left.

And in my game, I didn't want the player to be able to hang from a ledge so the transform.position was removed.
Changes:

Collision Script:

```
 isTouchingWall = Physics2D.Raycast(wallCheck.position, transform.right * move.side, wallCheckDistance, groundLayer);

        isTouchingLedge = Physics2D.Raycast(ledgeCheck.position, transform.right * move.side, wallCheckDistance, groundLayer);
```

ClimbLedge Function:

```
 private void CheckLedgeClimb()
    {

        if (coll.isTouchingWall && !coll.isTouchingLedge && !ledgeDetected)
        {
            //Reference point to startPos and stopPos
            ledgeDetected = true;
            //Freeze player in the detectedPos
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.gravityScale = 0f;
            transform.position = detectedPos;
            cornerPos = DetermineCornerPosition();
            Debug.Log("cornerPos Vector Value: " + cornerPos);
            canClimbLedge = false;
        }

        if(ledgeDetected && !canClimbLedge)
        {

            //This part is only necessary if you want the player to hang from a ledge.
            /*startPos.Set(cornerPos.x - (side * startOffset.x), cornerPos.y - startOffset.y);
            stopPos.Set(cornerPos.x + (side * stopOffset.x), cornerPos.y + stopOffset.y);

            Debug.Log("startPos when ledgeDetected + !canClimbLedge:" + startPos);
            canMove = false;
            transform.position = startPos;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.gravityScale = 0f;*/

            stopPos.Set(cornerPos.x + (side * stopOffset.x), cornerPos.y + stopOffset.y);
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.gravityScale = 0f;
            canMove = false;
            canClimbLedge = true;
        }
    }

    public void FinishLedgeClimb()
    {
       if (canClimbLedge)
        {
            transform.position = stopPos;
            canClimbLedge = false;
            canMove = true;
            ledgeDetected = false;
            Debug.Log("transform.position = stopPos");

            //anim.SetBool("canClimbLedge", canClimbLedge);
        } 
    }
```

This is working, but the timing of when the player transform.position to the stopPos, is sometimes delayed.